# Spritesheet PNG shown at different position on live website

Tags: css, png, scaling, sprite-sheet

For some reason the images (from a sprite sheet) on my live website are positioned differently to the local version. Its driving me crazy! On inspecting the element it seems the spritesheet is being scaled slightly differently when live, which is shifting the images further right than I want. Any ideas why?

Many thanks in advance!

The HTML:

```
    <div id="icon-container">
 <div class="icon">
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>            
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s2" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>            
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s3" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>    
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s4" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>            
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s5" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>    
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s6" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>            
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s7" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>            
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s8" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>    
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s9" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>            
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s10" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>        
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s11" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>            
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s12" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>            
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s13" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>    
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s14" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>            
    <a class="stretchy">
                    <img class="spacer" alt="icon" src="images/assets/spacer.png">
                    <img class="sprite s15" alt="" src="images/assets/spritesheet.png">
    </a>            
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.stretchy {display:block; position:relative; overflow:hidden; max-width:400px; }

.stretchy .spacer { width: 100%; height: auto; }
.stretchy .sprite {
     position:absolute; top:-5px; left:0; max-width:none; max-height:100%;
 }
.stretch img { width: 100%; }

.stretchy .sprite.s2 {left:-103%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s3 {left:-205%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s4 {left:-307%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s5 {left:-407%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s6 {left:-508%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s7 {left:-608%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s8 {left:-709%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s9 {left:-811%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s10 {left:-911%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s11 {left:-1012%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s12 {left:-1113%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s13 {left:-1216%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s14 {left:-1318%;}
.stretchy .sprite.s15 {left:-1418%;}
```

[image: Local website]

[image: Live website]

Comment: Can you post links to the working examples so we can compare?

Comment: Yeah sure http://edharrisondesign.com/pocketpictograms/

Comment: The CSS by itself doesn't help much.  Can you at least provide the HTML, too?

Comment: I have included the HTML above

Comment: Looks like it breaks when you change the screen width (testing in Chrome). I'm assuming the problem lies with how your `left ###%` is calculated.

Comment: I've never seen a sprite used the way you're doing it by actually placing the sprite as an img tag inside each anchor. I've only ever used a sprite as the background image on elements.

Comment: The tutorial I used to scale the sprites was this one. Its supposed to be the a good technique http://tobyj.net/responsive-sprites/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `.icon` class has a width of 20% which is wider than the pocket `.parallelogram` on my screen. The scaling of the pocket should be in sync with the icon scaling ... otherwise the pocket will be too small or out of center in comparison to the icons.

**Edit:** here is a jsfiddle for trying out stuff: http://jsfiddle.net/adnrz/
With the media queries at some point you scale the pocket but not the icons anymore hence the pockets gets draged to the side. And on the smalest screen size you dont cut the icons on the right place, so you display two half-icons.

Comment: Ah I see. My media queries are a mess! Think I'm going to do them again from scratch. Nice one for starting me off

Answer (score 3):

There's a little bit more CSS used than the lines you posted... skeleton.css e.g.
And there you also use width with %... Guess that's the reason.

Comment: Thanks but I tried it without linking to skeleton.css - still doesn't work.

Comment: You were spot on - it was the .icon width % throwing it off. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

I would position both the pocket and the icons at

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
```

and add

```
margin-left: -HALF_THEIR_WIDTH;
```

I'd do the same with vertical positioning (I guess you know how reading above)

From what I see on your webpage you are mixing fixed pixel values with percentages in a bad way.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah you are right - I need to sort out my scaling using percentages properly. Cheers